# Material UI GridTile height

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

I'm currently working with material ui and I'm running into an issue with GridLists. I have a GridList with multiple GridTiles and I don't see any way to change the height of each GridList separately. We are provided a prop for GridLists that let us specify the GridList cellHeight, but not for individual GridTiles. Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

GriList entry on material ui site [Material Ui Grid List](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/grid-list)

I currently have the following (which does not work).

```
<GridList style={gridListStyle}>
    <GridTile style={gridStyle1} titlePosition="bottom">
        <div>
            stuff
        </div>
    </GridTile>
    <GridTile style={gridStyle2}>
        <div>
           junk
        </div>
    </GridTile>
</GridList>
```

Comment: If I set `cellHeight` on `GridList` or the height for css `style` prop on a `GridTile` they both work for me (material 0.15.0).

Comment: The problem comes when you start giving them all individual styles with height and then they begin to overlap. There is no way to stop them from overlapping at some point when you dynamically resize the page.

Comment: @Igorsvee I think a better question to ask would be, how do I stop the GridTiles from overlapping one another?

Comment: Probably with margins and media queries @Shadowvail

Comment: @Igorsvee How do I just make the height of the GridTile 100% of the parent div? Fooling around with the chrome dev tools, I was able to get a 100% height onto the GridTile's div container. Only problem is that it is not directly editable via style props in the GridTile component. It's as if it is grabbing height from the GridList. Gridlist only allows exact height sizes...

Comment: It looks like GrideTile's have a 100% height set by default, [source code](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/GridList/GridTile.js#L15). Or you could try inspecting the parent div for height once the real dom has been rendered in `componentDidMount` and change the style of your Tile accordingly

Comment: @Igorsvee Ok I sort of did something similar to answer the question. While not an ideal solution, I ended up overriding the GridTile component's height but pushing 100% height !important up to the parent. This solved the problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not an ideal solution, I ended up overriding the height of the GridTile component by adding 100% height !important. This allowed me to set the height to exactly what I needed.

```
  var gridTileStyle= {
      position: 'relative',
      float: 'left',
      width: '100%',
      minHeight: '400px',
      minWidth: '664px',
      overflow: 'hidden',
      height: '100% !important'
}
```

This allowed the component to dynamically resize in the window as the page got smaller, without the GridTile underneathe it overlapping it. Hopefully this helps someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add some `flex` styling, which could help you with spacing your Tiles appropriately; for examples of flex settings available in `Material-UI` see https://material-ui.com/layout/grid/ (don't stop just because you see `grid` - I've successfully implemented these properties in a `GridList` too!).

Comment: @Shadowvail, did you find the above useful in providing an answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Setting `minHeight: '100vh'` 
helped me to get a grid element to height of 100%.
I tried all other elements and variants and did not help.